# Compiler optimization to reduce bytes of executable code

Tags: plugins, compiler-construction, compilation, compiler-optimization

Is it possible for a Compiler (for ex. javac) to scan your whole project for **unused methods and variables** before compilation and then compiles the project without those **unused methods and variables** such that you end up with fewer bytes of executable code.

If this would be a compiler optimization, I would create one huge library that contains all my helper methods and import it in all my projects and not worry that it being so huge could effect my Software size.

I understand this could be impossible, if you do not have the source code of those libraries you are using(importing), but I am speaking of the case where you **have the source code**.

Is there a tool/IDE plugin that does something similar? I would think this could be also done in one step ahead of the compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java's compiler doesn't do this natively, but you can use a tool like [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) or any number of other Java optimizers to remove unused code.

But, in your case, why don't you just compile your big software library once and put it on your classpath? That way you don't have to duplicate it at all.

Comment: If I compile my big Software Library using the normal java compiler, I would compile every single method in that Library although I am using just very few..

Comment: ProGuard seems to do exactly what I want. Why does a Java compiler not do this natively, it seems like a good optimization that will in all cases produce smaller byte code?

Comment: A `.jar` file might be used for more than just your program. `.jar`s can be linked into any program, so "dead" code might not be dead in another module.

Comment: I understand that. I mean for your module, why should you compile the whole jar when you only need exactly one method from it! Other modules linking this same jar to their project could be using exactly two methods from this jar and hence compile only 2 methods from this  .jar(without affecting the .jar itself)